# Google Analytics won't send ga('send', 'pageview') when on localhost

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We're adding Google Analytics to a Single Application Page website. As it doesn't support SPA by default, we call it directly when the URL hash is changed -

```
  ga('set', 'page', window.location.hash);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

But it sends nothing to GA; is it because of 'localhost' domain? I still can see initial HTML page load requests in the analytics reports, but no hash changes there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: don't use ga. If you started to use Google Analytics just recently, your init code will use gtag() so you need to use completely different tracking code -

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {'page_path': '/new-page.html'});
```